# Divide many columns by another column

Tags: r

Ok with

```
A <- c(1:10)
B <- c(2:11)
C <- c(3:12)
df1 <- data.frame(A,B,C)
```

I do not understand this error:

```
df2 <- df1 / df1[,"C"]
df2 <- df1[1:3,] / df1[1:3,"C"]

a <- subset (df1, select = c(A, B)) 
b <- subset (df1, select = c (C))
c <- a/b
## Error in Ops.data.frame(a, b) : 
##  ‘/’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
```

seeing that both have the same number of rows:

```
dim(a)
dim(b)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R automatically drops dimensions (unless you explicitly specify `drop=FALSE`) when the use of matrix indexing results in a dimension of size 1 (i.e., one row or one column), but using `subset()` on a data frame always results in a data frame (even if it's only one column):

```
> str(b)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ C: int  3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
> str(df1[,"C"])
 int [1:10] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

So dividing by `df1[,"C"]` is dividing by a numeric (integer) vector rather than by a data frame. The error `‘/’ only defined for equally-sized data frames` means that the two data frames should be *exactly* equally-sized (same number of rows *and* columns).

`sweep(df1,df1[,"C"],MARGIN=1,"/")` might be safer.

Comment: sweep works perfectly. I would have add a comment. If you do a filter like
`code`filter <- df1[df1$A >=2,]
that does not work:
`subset(df1, filter, select = c(A,B)] ) <- sweep(df1[,c("A","B")],df1[,"C"],MARGIN=1,"/")`

and that's work:
`df1[,c("A","B")] <- sweep(df1[,c("A","B")],df1[,"C"],MARGIN=1,"/")`

Answer (score 1):

Since they are not equally sized, i.e. different number of columns, it will throw error.

Below will divide `a` to `b`

```
c <- a/b$C
```